# How to receive, process, and send an email using Cloud Function, and Mail API?

Tags: python, email, google-app-engine, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to create a basic application to do the following using GCP:

1. Receive an email
2. Read the email
3. Process the text in the email body
4. Send the processed text to the original sender as email body

For example:

`example@example.com` sends an email with Subject `Process this` and Email body `Hello` to the [Google service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts). 
The python program ([Cloud functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/)) will programmatically read the email body as string, append `world!`, then send `Hello world!` to the `example@example.com` as email body with subject `Processed!`.

I have added `example@example.com` to [Mail API Authorised Senders](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/settings/emailsenders).

I found these GitHub code to [send](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/6f5f3bcb81779679a24e0964a6c57c0c7deabfac/appengine/standard/mail/send_mail.py) and [receive](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/6f5f3bcb81779679a24e0964a6c57c0c7deabfac/appengine/standard/mail/handle_incoming_email.py) email.

How do I use these in cloud functions to actively look for incoming email and respond with a appropriate email with respect to my process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your problem is that you don't know how to trigger you Cloud Function. In this case I would suggest you to read Google's documentation about [calling a Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/).

In your case, you could use this [Third Party API](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Parse_Webhook/inbound_email.html). What this API does is when you receive an e-mail, it sends an HTTP POST request with all the information that are included in the e-mail. This HTTP request will trigger your function.

Let me know if it was helpful.